# Having a bit of trouble with PHP echo

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, session-variables

Im having problems getting this piece of code to work. Theres definitely a problem and I think its towards the end. My goal is to assign a php session variable to a hidden field. Normally I would just echo the php inline within the value parameter however I'm on Wordpress and thats not an option. this is my attempt at a work around.

`echo "<input type='hidden' name='country' id='firstcountry' value='" . $_SESSION["first_country"] . "'/>";`

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what is happening now? Please define the exact problem and desired solution.

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded? If it isn't; do. It's required.

Comment: Ok. My desired outcome would be for a php session variable to be assigned to the hidden field. All I'm getting is the last two characters ' "; ' output

Comment: Which question did you just answer? Doesn't look like it was mine.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes assume that the session variable is properly set and the session has been started.

Comment: How is the session variable first been assigned? One line of code isn't much to go on. Or, are you asking how to do it?

Comment: So, is `session_start();` inside all those pages and that POST has indeed a value for it? Edit: You deleted your comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it was assigned on a previous page. I know for a fact that the variable itself isn't the issue as I've been using it else where on the page without issue. The problem is most likely in the syntax of this line. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: `session_start(); 
$_SESSION["first_country"] = "Canada"; 
echo "<input type='hidden' name='country' id='firstcountry' value='" . $_SESSION["first_country"] . "'/>";` which echo'd "Canada" in HTML source => `<input type='hidden' name='country' id='firstcountry' value='Canada'/>`

Comment: Btw, there seems to be a few weird characters in your code, so just copy/paste my above code. Then again, it might be Stack's fault.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is a bit confusing. I did not copy any of the session start or where you assigned the country. only the echo portion. i literarily just replaced that line with your line and magically it worked. There may have been some character weirdness going on. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll just post my comment as an answer to close the question and make a few additional notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end of your code's line seems to contain two unidentifiable characters that could break your code.

Copy/paste the following, while changing the appropriate variable to the assigned POST.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION["first_country"] = "Canada"; 
echo "<input type='hidden' name='country' id='firstcountry' value='" . $_SESSION["first_country"] . "'/>";

?>
```

which echo'd "Canada" in HTML source in my test, as shown below:

`<input type='hidden' name='country' id='firstcountry' value='Canada'/>`

---

**Edit:**

After pasting it into my IDE, the two characters were a Unicode Character 'LINE SEPARATOR' (U+2028) - `&#8232;`

For more information on this Unicode character, visit the following Websites:

- **http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm**
- **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters**